MJML Elements and attributes not recognized when calling MJML API to render HTML
I am trying to generate MJML with MarkupTemplateEngine in a groovy script, then render it to HTML by calling mjml's API.
Here's a code sample :
import groovy.text.markup.*

TemplateConfiguration config = new TemplateConfiguration();
def engine = new MarkupTemplateEngine(config)

def style = '''<mj-style>.main div{ line-height: 23.4px !important; font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important; }</mj-style>
'''
String mjmlTemplate = '''
mjml {'mj-head' yieldUnescaped (style)
  'mj-body'(backgroundColor: "#121212", cssClass: "main") {
    yieldUnescaped (header)
    'mj-section'(backgroundColor: "#121212") {
      'mj-column'(width: "60%", verticalAlign: "middle") {
        'mj-text'(color: "white", fontWeight: "900", fontSize: "24px") {
          yield("Hello World ")
        }
}
}
}
}

def model = [ style: style, header: header]
def template = engine.createTemplate(mjmlTemplate)
def mjml = template.make(model).toString()

println mjml


when I call the API it returns a list of errors for example:
{
            "line": 1,
            "message": "Attributes backgroundColor, cssClass are illegal",
            "tagName": "mj-body",
            "formattedMessage": "Line 1 of /home/ndjs (mj-body) — Attributes backgroundColor, cssClass are illegal"
        },
 {
            "line": 1,
            "message": "mj-section cannot be used inside mj-section, only inside: mj-attributes, mj-body, mj-wrapper",
            "tagName": "mj-section",
            "formattedMessage": "Line 1 of /home/ndjs (mj-section) — mj-section cannot be used inside mj-section, only inside: mj-attributes, mj-body, mj-wrapper"
        }

When I fix the elemnts in the template, for example replace backgroundColor by background-color in mjmlTemplate
the groovy script gives this error :
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
GeneratedMarkupTemplate0: 2: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 2, column 6.
   mjml {'mj-head' yieldUnescaped (style)
        ^

1 error


Minus in symbol? Quote

Not sure this is a duplicate  anyway... Replace backgroundColor with 'background-color' (with quotes)

replacing it with quotes worked thank you
